# Scrollbar above content, overlay works in halfway

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I need:

1. scrollbar that takes no space/no width of scrollable container (`.viewport`)
2. scrollbar track/background to be transparent
3. (`.content`) of container(`.viewport`) to be visible under scrollbar thumb

**First** I did by setting (`.viewport`) `overflow-y` to `overlay` value. **Second** I did by setting `background: transparent;` to `::-webkit-scrollbar` **Third** intuitively should happen but did not.

The green bg from screenshot comes from (`.viewport`) but there should be darkblue bg with text from (`.content`).

[image: jsfiddle-screenshot-with-details]

---

Code & jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h2e6dumo/

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #444444;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.viewport {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000044;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="content">Praesent leo metus, aliquet non orci facilisis, rhoncus aliquet tellus. Curabitur est libero, commodo luctus diam eu, mattis tempus est. Nulla facilisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam
    finibus enim interdum odio placerat pulvinar. Fusce ac rhoncus lorem. Etiam ultrices, velit eu ultrices lobortis, mi quam accumsan tellus, ac vehicula lectus odio in tellus. Duis euismod, velit et ultricies viverra, tellus lectus ornare enim, molestie
    sodales lectus nisi dignissim leo. Donec consequat nisi quis dui scelerisque, ac ultricies nisl placerat. In ut nunc feugiat, gravida lacus non, sagittis ante. Mauris urna tellus, mattis ac libero at, gravida fermentum leo. Curabitur neque leo, convallis
    tempus massa in, sollicitudin euismod enim. Phasellus velit eros, porttitor nec laoreet vitae, interdum id ex. Nulla nec elementum massa.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's no possible with CSS only. You can use [this customizable plugin for jQuery](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/demo/)